# From $ \sum^\infty_{\lfloor \log n \rfloor + 1}n/{2^r} $ to $ \sum^\infty_{r=0}1/2^r $?

Tags: inequality, summation, logarithms, self-learning

$$
E[h] = E[\sum^\infty_{r=1}I_r]
= \sum^\infty_{r=1}E[I_r]
$$

$$
= \sum^{ \lfloor \log n \rfloor}_{r=1}E[I_r] + \sum^\infty_{\lfloor \log n \rfloor + 1}E[I_r]
$$

$$
\leq
\sum^{ \lfloor \log n \rfloor}_{r=1}1 + \sum^\infty_{\lfloor \log n \rfloor + 1}n/{2^r}
$$

$$
\leq
\log n + \sum^\infty_{r=0}1/2^r
$$

$$
= \log n + 2
$$

I'm trying to understand how you go from $ \sum^\infty_{\lfloor \log n \rfloor + 1}n/{2^r} $ to $ \sum^\infty_{r=0}1/2^r $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming $\log$ here means the base-$2$ logarithm (since the inequality doesn't generally hold if the base is larger), we have

$$n < 2^{\lfloor \log n\rfloor+1},$$

and therefore

$$\sum_{r=\lfloor \log n\rfloor+1}^\infty \frac{n}{2^r} < \sum_{r=\lfloor \log n\rfloor+1}^\infty \frac{2^{\lfloor \log n\rfloor+1}}{2^r} = \sum_{r=\lfloor \log n\rfloor+1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^{r-(\lfloor\log n\rfloor+1)}} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2^k}.$$

Comment: So you're saying $ n < 2^{\lfloor \log n\rfloor+1} $
But how is $ r=\lfloor \log n \rfloor + 1 $ transformed into $ k = 0 $ ?

Comment: Substitute $k = r - (\lfloor \log n\rfloor + 1)$.

Comment: In the original post, $k=0$ wasn't used but $r=0$ was. Isn't it strange to say $ r = r - (\lfloor \log n \rfloor + 1) $ ?

Comment: That's why I called it $k$. I could now make another step and rename $k$ to $r$, then I'd have the same as the original. But I think it's better to see what's going on when I use a new letter for the shifted index.

Comment: Not quite, $2^{\lfloor \log n\rfloor} \leqslant n < 2^{\lfloor\log n\rfloor + 1}\leqslant 2\cdot n$, but in general you don't have equality at the left.